# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.core.server.NettyServer when more play libraries are added to build.sbt

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am new-ish to Scala, SBT and Play so please treat this as a NooB questtion. I am building an example Play application for a contest, and started with the reactive-stocks application as a template. To expand on its functionality naturally I need to add Security, JDBC connections etc.

This is the original build.sbt file supplied in the template -

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ws, // Play's web services module
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.3.4",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1",
  "org.webjars" % "flot" % "0.8.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.4" % "test"
)
```

over this i added  "com.typesafe.play" % "anorm_2.11" % "2.4.0-M1", to the list just after the slf4j dependency and the application is able to compile and run.

Now if I add any of "com.typesafe.play" % "filters-helpers_2.11" % "2.4.0-M1" or "com.typesafe.play" % "play-jdbc_2.11" % "2.4.0-M1",
the play application fails to compile in Activator web ui with the message "(echo:run) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.core.server.NettyServer".

### The Netty Server class is definitely in the classpath. What is the problem then?

I am using JDK 8. The failing config is

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ws, // Play's web services module
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.3.4",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1",
  "org.webjars" % "flot" % "0.8.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.4" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "anorm_2.11" % "2.4.0-M1",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "filters-helpers_2.11" % "2.4.0-M1",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-jdbc_2.11" % "2.4.0-M1"
)
```

with the log

```
Reapplying settings...
Set current project to reactive-stocks (in build file:/D:/Miura/reactive-stocks/)
Reapplying settings...
Set current project to reactive-stocks (in build file:/D:/Miura/reactive-stocks/)
Reapplying settings...
Set current project to reactive-stocks (in build file:/D:/Miura/reactive-stocks/)
Reapplying settings...
Set current project to reactive-stocks (in build file:/D:/Miura/reactive-stocks/)
Running task... Cancel: sbt.TaskCancellationStrategy$Null$@571cf19b, check cycles: false
play.core.server.NettyServer
(echo:run) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.core.server.NettyServer
Run complete.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered on the [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/OwPZHeQdfyY), the problem was because of mixing up Play library versions. The stocks template is for Play 2.3.3 but the libraries I was trying to add are for 2.4.

This config in build.sbt works

```
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     jdbc,
     anorm,
     cache,
     ws
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that error too:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/core/server/NettyServer
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.core.server.NettyServer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
```

But my problem was more stupid: Permissions. Check if the user that is executing the application has the right permissions.

Just for the records, so others can save time.